# AAD Change Notifications - Delta query to track recent changes using "$deltaToken=latest"

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I have created brand new AAD Group, added a couple of users to it, and removed users from it. I then tried the below request and it's returning a `deltalink` as expected:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/groups/delta/?$filter= id eq '900faee0-0115-44a9-876w-cd1644472792'&$deltaToken=latest
```

When trying to call the `deltaLink` I received using the above request, I'm getting an empty response without the expected `members@delta` showing recently added or deleted Users.

Note: I didn't try the delta function on the desired resource as I'm not interested in retrieving the full state of the resource but trying above `$deltaToken=latest` request as very first delta change query.

Comment: Where did you find this $deltaToken=latest? I can't see it in the docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-delta

Comment: From below MSDN link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/delta-query-overview, under section, "Note: Resources stored in Azure Active Directory (such as users and groups) support "sync from now" scenarios. This allows you to skip steps 1 and 2 above (if you are not interested in retrieving the full state of the resource) and ask for the latest deltaLink instead. Append $deltaToken=latest to the delta function and the response will contain a deltaLink and no resource data."

Answer (score 1):

The reason you're not seeing membership changes is that you haven't expanded members in your query. Your current question will only return changes to the Group itself, not related entities.

To retrieve a delta for the Group & Members your query should be:

```
/v1.0/groups/delta/?$expand=members&$filter= id eq '900faee0-0115-44a9-876w-cd1644472792'&$deltaToken=latest
```

Also, note that you really shouldn't call the Graph Beta version unless your testing new Graph features. The Beta APIs can *and will* see breaking changes occur without warning. It is not safe for production code.

Comment: Im not expecting delta member to be returned from after executing "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/delta/?$filter= id eq '900faee0-0115-44a9-876w-cd1644472792'&$deltaToken=latest". This query request returns delta link as expected, but expecting delta members to get returned when executing that received delta link. Will my expectation works? or only delta link works only after atleast one time execution of "delta function query"? Please suggest.

Comment: If you want to see membership changes then you need to include `$expand=members` in your initial call. Without it, the `deltaLink` that gets generated will not include membership changes.

Comment: Do you have sample Graph API SDK code to get $deltaToken=latest? please

Comment: Hi @MarcLaFleur , what does $deltaToken=latest mean, I am looking a day worth of delta for users, is there a way i can mention the delta by from/to date

Comment: `$deltaToken=latest` is just a short-cut for returning a `deltaLink` rather than having to cycle through each `nextLink` until you reach the final page. It will return the same first page as a normal Delta query, but instead of a `nextLink` for page #2, it returns a `deltaLink`. You normally use this when you only care about changes going forward.

Comment: Note that `$deltaLink=latest` doesn't work with every endpoint. The AAD endpoints generally support it but many others (Exchange for example) do not.